# Facebook login plugin how to hide text: "[username] uses [appname]"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, hide

Haven't found the answer to this, but I'm still looking how to remove the text.

When a user logs in, the facebook login button will turn into a logout button, but it also shows this text: http://gyazo.com/fcc1429b6f7207ffab14556384386374

"Username" uses "Appname" together with a profile pic.
(I'd also like to hide the profile pic)

Does anyone know if there's a extra secret thing for it? I know the logout button was something "secret" (it wasn't listed in the official docs) where you had to add autologoutlink="true".
So, I'm wondering if there's a thing like that to hide the text with image.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can hide the images and the text you specified by using `show-faces='false'` but as for hiding just the text, it seems to be a mystery!

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/